Problem with @ConfigProperty in null when using a process in Apache Camel Quarkus
Good morning, I am currently working with Quarkus and Apache Camel and I am using a variable from the application.properties in a processor, I try to bring it in using the @ConfigProperty annotation, but it is giving me a null error, this is how I have it configured:
The variable is called encryptionKey
UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq
@ApplicationScoped
@Slf4j
public class UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq implements Processor {

    @ConfigProperty(name="aes.encrypt.key")
    String encryptionKey;

    private final IValidationFieldsUserID validationFields;

    public UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq() {
        validationFields = new ValidationFieldsUserID();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        String documentType;
        String documentNumber;
        String userId;
        String correlatorId;
        String tokenInfo;
        String userIdDecodedBase64;
        String userIdDecrypt;

        try {
            correlatorId= Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getIn().getHeader("x-correlator")).map(Object::toString).orElse("");
            exchange.setProperty("correlatorId",correlatorId);
            userId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("user_id").toString();
            tokenInfo= Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getIn().getHeader("x-token-info")).map(Object::toString).orElse("");
            validationFields.validateUserId(exchange);
            userId=validateUserIdValue(userId, tokenInfo);
            exchange.setProperty("userIdEncrypt", userId);
            userIdDecodedBase64= EncodeBase64.decrypt(userId);
            log.info("userIdDecodedBase64" + userIdDecodedBase64);
            userIdDecrypt= EncryptUtil.decrypt(userIdDecodedBase64,encryptionKey);
            exchange.setProperty("userId", userIdDecrypt);
            validateTokenInfo(exchange,userId, tokenInfo);
            validateUserIdDecrypt(userIdDecrypt);
            documentType = userIdDecrypt.split("-")[0];
            documentNumber = userIdDecrypt.split("-")[1];
            exchange.setProperty("documentType", documentType);
            exchange.setProperty("documentNumber", documentNumber);
            exchange.setProperty("isSearchByQueryParam","false");

        } catch (RequiredValueException | NullPointerException e) {
            throw new RequiredValueException(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (NotFoundDataException e) {
            throw new NotFoundDataException(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (PermissionDeniedException e) {
            throw new PermissionDeniedException(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            if( e.getMessage().contains("Input byte array"))
                throw new NotFoundDataException(e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void validateTokenInfo(Exchange exchange, String userId, String tokenInfoValidated) {
        if (!tokenInfoValidated.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Valor del x-token-info: {}", tokenInfoValidated);
            /* Se obtiene el Objeto JSON con el valor del campo x-token-info */
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(tokenInfoValidated);
            /*String subValue=jsonObject.get("sub").toString(); */
            /* Mediante el optString obtenemos el valor sub si viene (token 3 patas) o no viene (token 2 patas), para este ultimo caso el valor es vacio */
            String subValue = jsonObject.optString("sub");
            log.info("Valor sub que esta llegando en el valor x-token-info: {}", subValue);
            if (!subValue.isEmpty()) {
                if(!subValue.equals(userId)) {
                    throw new PermissionDeniedException("Error validando el campo sub de la autenticacion en el campo x-token-info, no hace match con userId enviado");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Se valida que el UserId sea un valor valido para venezuela, sea enviado cifrado o no*/
    private static void validateUserIdDecrypt (String userId) {
        if(!Pattern.matches("^(CI|RIF|P|CD|NIT)(-).*",userId)){
            throw  new NotFoundDataException("UserId enviado esta en formato incorrecto");
        }
    }
    /*Se valida el valor del campo UserId, si el mismo pudiera contener el valor de me, en este caso se debe extraer el valor de UserId del json token-info, en especifico del campo sub */
    private String validateUserIdValue(String userId,String tokenInfo) {
        if(userId.equals("me")){
            if(!tokenInfo.isEmpty()){
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(tokenInfo);
                userId = jsonObject.optString("sub");
            }
            else {
                throw new RequiredValueException("Se requiere parametro x-token-info (autenticacion 3 patas) para campo userId=me");
            }
        }
        return userId;
    }
}

And this is the error it gives:
14:52:44 INFO  traceId=2a0a8e8cd93ddb947e2ab7206ef4f25d, parentId=, spanId=394c6d08dec8d551, sampled=true [route23] (vert.x-worker-thread-0) [2024-07-01 14:52:44.0] Descripcion de la Exception: Cannot invoke "String.getBytes()" because "key" is null

This is how it is in my application.properties:
aes.encrypt.key=${AES_ENCRYPT_KEY:xxxxxxxxxxxx}

Like from ResRoute call to processor without constructor:
from("direct:usersQueryParam")
                /*.removeHeaders("CamelHttp*") */
                .doTry()
                .process(new UserProfileProcessorQueryParamReq())
                .choice()
                /* code */

How can I do here so that it takes the value of the @ConfigProperty?

I think it's not working because you're creating the Processor manually. Try to pass the encryptionKey as a constructor parameter and move your @ConfigProperty to the route builder:
UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq
@Slf4j
public class UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq implements Processor {

    private String encryptionKey;

    private final IValidationFieldsUserID validationFields;

    public UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq(String encryptionKey) {
        validationFields = new ValidationFieldsUserID();
        this.encryptionKey = encryptionKey;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        String documentType;
        String documentNumber;
        String userId;
        String correlatorId;
        String tokenInfo;
        String userIdDecodedBase64;
        String userIdDecrypt;

        try {
            correlatorId= Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getIn().getHeader("x-correlator")).map(Object::toString).orElse("");
            exchange.setProperty("correlatorId",correlatorId);
            userId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("user_id").toString();
            tokenInfo= Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getIn().getHeader("x-token-info")).map(Object::toString).orElse("");
            validationFields.validateUserId(exchange);
            userId=validateUserIdValue(userId, tokenInfo);
            exchange.setProperty("userIdEncrypt", userId);
            userIdDecodedBase64= EncodeBase64.decrypt(userId);
            log.info("userIdDecodedBase64" + userIdDecodedBase64);
            userIdDecrypt= EncryptUtil.decrypt(userIdDecodedBase64,encryptionKey);
            exchange.setProperty("userId", userIdDecrypt);
            validateTokenInfo(exchange,userId, tokenInfo);
            validateUserIdDecrypt(userIdDecrypt);
            documentType = userIdDecrypt.split("-")[0];
            documentNumber = userIdDecrypt.split("-")[1];
            exchange.setProperty("documentType", documentType);
            exchange.setProperty("documentNumber", documentNumber);
            exchange.setProperty("isSearchByQueryParam","false");

        } catch (RequiredValueException | NullPointerException e) {
            throw new RequiredValueException(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (NotFoundDataException e) {
            throw new NotFoundDataException(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (PermissionDeniedException e) {
            throw new PermissionDeniedException(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            if( e.getMessage().contains("Input byte array"))
                throw new NotFoundDataException(e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void validateTokenInfo(Exchange exchange, String userId, String tokenInfoValidated) {
        if (!tokenInfoValidated.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Valor del x-token-info: {}", tokenInfoValidated);
            /* Se obtiene el Objeto JSON con el valor del campo x-token-info */
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(tokenInfoValidated);
            /*String subValue=jsonObject.get("sub").toString(); */
            /* Mediante el optString obtenemos el valor sub si viene (token 3 patas) o no viene (token 2 patas), para este ultimo caso el valor es vacio */
            String subValue = jsonObject.optString("sub");
            log.info("Valor sub que esta llegando en el valor x-token-info: {}", subValue);
            if (!subValue.isEmpty()) {
                if(!subValue.equals(userId)) {
                    throw new PermissionDeniedException("Error validando el campo sub de la autenticacion en el campo x-token-info, no hace match con userId enviado");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Se valida que el UserId sea un valor valido para venezuela, sea enviado cifrado o no*/
    private static void validateUserIdDecrypt (String userId) {
        if(!Pattern.matches("^(CI|RIF|P|CD|NIT)(-).*",userId)){
            throw  new NotFoundDataException("UserId enviado esta en formato incorrecto");
        }
    }
    /*Se valida el valor del campo UserId, si el mismo pudiera contener el valor de me, en este caso se debe extraer el valor de UserId del json token-info, en especifico del campo sub */
    private String validateUserIdValue(String userId,String tokenInfo) {
        if(userId.equals("me")){
            if(!tokenInfo.isEmpty()){
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(tokenInfo);
                userId = jsonObject.optString("sub");
            }
            else {
                throw new RequiredValueException("Se requiere parametro x-token-info (autenticacion 3 patas) para campo userId=me");
            }
        }
        return userId;
    }
}

ResRoute
    package org.tmve.customer.ms.route;
    
    import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
    import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
    import org.apache.camel.component.caffeine.CaffeineConstants;
    import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
    import org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException;
    import org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException;
    import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
    import org.tmve.customer.ms.beans.response.UserProfile;
    import org.tmve.customer.ms.exceptions.NotFoundDataException;
    import org.tmve.customer.ms.exceptions.EmptyDataExceptionQueryParam;
    import org.tmve.customer.ms.exceptions.PermissionDeniedException;
    import org.tmve.customer.ms.exceptions.RequiredValueException;
    import org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.*;
    import org.tmve.customer.ms.utilities.BeanDate;
    
    import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    
    import static org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestParamType.body;
    
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class ResRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
        @ConfigProperty(name="aes.encrypt.key")
        String encryptionKey;
    
        @ConfigProperty(name="client.findCustomerByDocId")
        String findCustomerByDocId;
    
        @ConfigProperty(name="client.findCustomerAccountListByDocId")
        String findCustomerAccountsListByDocId;
    
        @ConfigProperty(name="client.findPostpaidAccountInfo")
        String findPostpaidAccountInfo;
    
        @ConfigProperty(name="client.findCustomerDocumentBySubscriberId")
        String findCustomerDocumentBySubscriberId;
    
        @ConfigProperty(name="client.findFeatureByAccount")
        String findFeatureByAccount;
        @ConfigProperty(name = "path.openapi")
        String openApiPath;
        @ConfigProperty(name = "descripcion.servicio")
        String serviceDescription;
        private ConfigureSsl configureSsl;
        private static final String SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION = "Salida del microservicio BSS UserProfile ${exchangeProperty[bodyRs]}";
        private static final String USER_PROFILE = "UserProfile";
        private static final String MSG_EXCEPTION = "Descripcion de la Exception: ${exception.message}";
    
        private static final String DATE_LOG = "[${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}] ";
    
        private static final String DIRECT_PIPELINE = "direct:pipeline";
    
        public ResRoute() {
            configureSsl = new ConfigureSsl();
        }
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
    
            BeanDate beanDate= new BeanDate();
            getContext().getRegistry().bind("BeanDate",beanDate);
    
            restConfiguration()
                    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                    .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
                    .apiContextPath(openApiPath)
                    .apiProperty("api.title", USER_PROFILE)
                    .apiProperty("api.description", serviceDescription)
                    .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0")
                    .apiProperty("cors", "true");
    
            rest("userProfile/v3/")
                    .get("/users/{user_id}").to("direct:/{user_id}")
                        .outType(UserProfile.class)
                        .param().name(USER_PROFILE).type(body).description("parametro de salida").required(true)
                        .endParam()
                        .to("direct:userIdParam");
            rest("/userProfile/v3/")
                    .get("/users?").to("direct:/users?")
                    .outType(UserProfile.class)
                    .param().name(USER_PROFILE).type(body).description("parametro de salida").required(true).endParam()
                    .to("direct:usersQueryParam");
    
            onException(RequiredValueException.class)
                    .handled(true)
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessorInvalidFormatException())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                    .log(DATE_LOG+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
            onException(NotFoundDataException.class)
                    .handled(true)
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessorInformationSubscriber())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                    .log(DATE_LOG+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
            onException(HttpHostConnectException.class)
                    .handled(true)
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessHttpHostConectionException())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                    .log(DATE_LOG+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
            onException(PermissionDeniedException.class)
                    .handled(true)
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessorPermissionDenied())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                    .log(DATE_LOG+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
            onException(Exception.class)
                    .handled(true)
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessorException())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                    .log(DATE_LOG+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
            from("direct:userIdParam")
                    .doTry()
                            .process(new UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq(encryptionKey))
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"User ID: ${exchangeProperty[userId]}")
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"UserId Encrypt: ${exchangeProperty[userIdEncrypt]}")
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"Correlator ID: ${exchangeProperty[correlatorId]}")
                    .endDoTry()
                    .to(DIRECT_PIPELINE);
            from("direct:usersQueryParam")
                    /*.removeHeaders("CamelHttp*") */
                    .doTry()
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessorQueryParamReq())
                    .choice()
                        .when(simple("${exchangeProperty[isSearchByQueryParamIdDocumentValueAndIdDocumentType]} == 'true'"))
                            .to(DIRECT_PIPELINE)
                        .otherwise()
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"Identity: ${exchangeProperty[identityQueryParam]}")
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"IdentityType: ${exchangeProperty[identityTypeQueryParam]}")
                            .process(new FindCustomerDocumentBySubscriberIdReq())
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"Entrada Microservicio FindCustomerDocumentBySubscriberId: ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerDocumentBySubscriberIdRequest]}")
                            .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findCustomerDocumentBySubscriberId))
                            .process(new FindCustomerDocumentBySubscriberIdRes())
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"Salida FindCustomerDocumentBySubscriberId: ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerDocumentBySubscriberIdResponseStatus]}")
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"User ID Mediante QueryParam: ${exchangeProperty[userId]}")
                            .to(DIRECT_PIPELINE)
                    .endDoTry()
                    /*.to(DIRECT_PIPELINE) */
                    .doCatch(EmptyDataExceptionQueryParam.class)
                    .process(new UserProfileEmptyDataSubscriberQueryParam())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                    .log(DATE_LOG+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
    
            from(DIRECT_PIPELINE)
                    .doTry()
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"UserId: ${exchangeProperty[userId]}")
                    .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorReq())
                    .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findCustomerByDocId))
                    .choice()
                    .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isEqualTo(200))
                        .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorRes())
                        .log(DATE_LOG+"Mensaje Ejecucion MS FindCustomerByDocId: ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerByDocIdResponseMessage]}")
                    .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isEqualTo(404))
                            .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorResHttp404())
                            .log(DATE_LOG+"Mensaje Ejecucion MS FindCustomerByDocId: ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerByDocIdResponseMessage]}")
                    .otherwise()
                    .log("Error al consultar Microservicio FindCustomerByDocId con codigo de respuesta: ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}")
                        .process(new UserProfileFaultProcessRes())
                    .end()
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Document userId: ${exchangeProperty[userDocument]}")
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Name userId: ${exchangeProperty[userName]}")
                    .process(new FindCustomerAccountListByDocIdReq())
                    .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findCustomerAccountsListByDocId))
                    .choice()
                    .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isEqualTo(200))
                        .process(new FindCustomerAccountsListByDocIdRes())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Mensaje Ejecucion MS FindCustomerAccountListByDocId: ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerAccountListByDocIdResponseMessage]}")
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Total Cuentas Prepago: ${exchangeProperty[prepaidAccountCount]}")
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Total Cuentas Pospago: ${exchangeProperty[postpaidAccountCount]}")
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Cuentas Prepago: ${exchangeProperty[prepaidAccounts]}")
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Cuentas Pospago: ${exchangeProperty[postpaidAccounts]}")
                    .otherwise()
                    .log("Error al consultar Microservicio FindCustomerAccountsListByDocId con codigo de respuesta: ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}")
                        .process(new UserProfileFaultProcessRes())
                    .end()
                    .loop(simple("${exchangeProperty[postpaidAccountCount]}"))
                        .process(new FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessReq())
                        .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_GET))
                        .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY).exchangeProperty("postpaidAccount")
                        .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "SVAPostpaid")
                        .choice().when(header(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_HAS_RESULT).isEqualTo(Boolean.FALSE))
                            .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findPostpaidAccountInfo))
                            .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_PUT))
                            .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY).exchangeProperty("postpaidAccount")
                            .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "SVAPostpaid")
                            .process(new FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessRes())
                        .otherwise()
                            .process(new FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessRes())
                        .end()
                    .end()
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Busqueda SVA para Cuentas Pospago Exitosa....")
                    .loop(simple("${exchangeProperty[prepaidAccountCount]}"))
                        .process(new FindFeaturesByAccountProcessorReq())
                        .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_GET))
                        .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY).exchangeProperty("prepaidAccount")
                        .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "SVAPrepaid")
                        .choice().when(header(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_HAS_RESULT).isEqualTo(Boolean.FALSE))
                            .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findFeatureByAccount))
                            .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_PUT))
                            .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY).exchangeProperty("prepaidAccount")
                            .toF("caffeine-cache://%s", "SVAPrepaid")
                            .process(new FindFeatureByAccountProcessorRes())
                        .otherwise()
                            .process(new FindFeatureByAccountProcessorRes())
                        .end()
                    .end()
                    .log(DATE_LOG+"Busqueda SVA para Cuentas Prepago Exitosa....")
                    .choice()
                    .when(simple("${exchangeProperty[isSearchByQueryParam]} == 'true'"))
                        .process(new UserProfileProcessorQueryParamRes())
                        .log(DATE_LOG+"Salida MS UserProfile: ${exchangeProperty[userProfileResponse]}")
                    .otherwise()
                        .process(new UserProfileProcessorUserIdRes())
                        .log(DATE_LOG+"Salida MS UserProfile: ${exchangeProperty[userProfileResponse]}")
                    .endDoTry()
                    .doCatch(UnknownHostException.class)
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessHttpHostConectionException())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                    .log(DATE_LOG+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                    .doCatch(NoHttpResponseException.class)
                    .process(new UserProfileProcessHttpHostConectionException())
                    .log(DATE_LOG+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                    .log(DATE_LOG+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }


When applying this I get the following error:
aused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type java.lang.String and qualifiers [@Default]

java member: org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq():encryptionKey
declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.apache.camel.Processor


org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.UserProfileProcessorUserIdParamReq]
The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:

Bean [class=java.lang.String, qualifiers=[@ConfigProperty, @Any]]


Can you please include your complete RouteBuilder class, also with the includes section in the original question?

And did you remove the @ApplicationScoped annotation from your Processor?

That's it, I had to remove the annotation @ApplicationScoped my Processor, now it works

Why was it necessary to remove ApplicationScoped from my processor?

As this is basically telling quarkus to create and configure the class automatically. But as you're creating it by your own during the .process(...) you can pass everything you want there and you don't want that it's getting created automatically. That's basically the same reason, why we deleted the annotation in the processor, because we don't want to configure it during auto creation. When it was annotated, it was of course complaining about the missing value for encryptionKey because we removed the @ConfigProperty

I've corrected the answer, by removing the @ApplicationScoped annotation from the processor.
